# Подставить имя массива из аргумента функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли подставить имя массива из переменной.

По типу:

```
const Array = [1,2,3];
var i = 0;

foo("Array");

function foo(str){

console.log(str[i]);

}
```

Если подобное невозможно, посоветуйте, что можно сделать?

Comment: можно так: `foo(Array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var context = {
  a: 123,
  Array: [1, 2, 3]
}
var i = 0;

foo(context, "Array");

function foo(context, str) {
  console.log(context[str][i]);
}
```